# How do I add a name to a launcher?

Tags: 11.04, launcher

I added application to launcher like this. I run it from command line, then when icon appeared in launcher, I right clicked it and checked "Keep In Launcher".

It works fine, but I'd like to add name to this launcher icon. When I hover over some other icon in the lanucher, a name appears. On icon I added there is no name. How can I add one?

Answer (score 5):

Hi the most basic *.desktop file you could create would be:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=eclipse
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
```

This is an example I use for eclipse. I created it like this

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

After that you have to make it executable with

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

Than if you want to add it to the launcher just execute it (navigate to /usr/share/applications/ and double click eclipse) and right click on the icon in the laucher and select "Keep In Laucher"
The application will now also be displayed when you search for applications in the application lens.

Comment: It doesn't work. Probably because I run script, which runs the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

Find the *.place (*desktop) and add the option

Name={your descripton}

Example with the Ask Ubuntu lens:

askubuntu.place:

```
[Place]
DBusName=net.launchpad.AskUbuntuPlace
DBusObjectPath=/net/launchpad/askubuntuplace

[Entry:Stuff]
DBusObjectPath=/net/launchpad/askubuntuplace/mainentry
Icon=/usr/share/unity-place-askubuntu/askubuntu-place.png
Name=Ask Ubuntu
Description=Ask Questions and Get Answers on Ask Ubuntu
SearchHint=Search Ask Ubuntu
Shortcut=u

[Desktop Entry]
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=askubuntu-place
```

Comment: Where should I look for the *.place?

Comment: amorfis: looks like it either is /usr/share/unity/places or /usr/share/app-install/desktop But you made that launcher yourself (?)

Comment: At /usr/share/unity/places I have only applications.place and files.place. At /usr/share/app-install/desktop I have a lot of *.desktop files, but no *.place file.

Comment: Look in .local/share/applications

Comment: Thanks @Jorge, but it's not there :(

Comment: @amorfis: could you tell us what application you added? Maybe someone can figure out what file you need to alter ;) and I do not know if this is possible but it could also be a desktop file you need to find.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new text file and paste this:

`[Desktop Entry]

Name=

Comment=

Exec=

Icon=Google-Tools

Terminal=false

Type=Application

StartupNotify=true`

Fill in the desired name, comment and command. Save it as a .desktop file and move it to ~/.local/share/applications

Log out, and log back in and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Launchers is just *.desktop files. You can find most of them in /usr/share/applications folder. Just Drag & Drop the *.desktop files into your unity launch bar and that's it. Or more easly, search the app with the dashboard (in serach mode with `<Alt><F2>` command or with the 'Application Lens' (`<Super><A>`) and drag and drop the shortcut from the dash to the launcher bar.

But maybe the app is a script that you created or something like this, not referenced in Ubuntu. In this case you can create your own launcher as Leron said (you can change the icon too ;) )

I hope my explaination will help you

BR,