# Is there a way to change the icon of a running application on the Gnome panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, panel, icons

I would like to change the icon of running applications like Opera. When running both Opera Next and Opera, the two versions both appear at the top panel, but both are in red. I want to change the Opera Next icon so it is easier to identify when the windows are minimized.

Is there a way to change the icons that show for running applications in the panel?

Comment: the easiest would be to chnage the opera next icon itself,but i don't know where it is located 'cause i don't have it installed

Comment: Which ubuntu version are we talking about i assumed 11.04

Comment: opera next icon (grey color) is different already just appears different (red) in gnome panel from the one at applications panel (which is gray)... my question still the same how do i change the icons of running applications in gnome-panel? maverick 10.10

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the same as for this Question:
[How do I add a name to a launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38819/how-do-i-add-a-name-to-a-launcher/41642#41642)
create a *.desktop file like I describe there and set the Icon to the path were you put the icon you want to use.
This will change the launcher icon system wide changing it just for the unity panel at runtime is not possible as far as I know